# Bower install error eacces permission denied

Tags: macos, npm, bower, package-managers, bower-install

Hi I searched and tried all possible answers given in different sections but it still gives an error.

```
you donot have access of this file ../././bower-github.json
```

Attached the screen shot[image]

Comment: Have you tried `chmod`ing the file

Comment: Yes I tried, but it has same error.

Comment: I have given permission to each and every file inside the configstore folder and then it is working .

Answer (score 0):

I have given `chomd` permission to each and every file inside the directory .cofig/configstore folder (bower-github.json and update-notifier-bower.json)and then it is working.

As written in many post I tried to `chomd` on configstore root folder and it was failing to get the permission of 2 files which I have mentioned above.

Please check console in case if you find any error and try to give `chomd` for the specific file it says in error.